# WSo2 ESB Smooks Mediator Error

Tags: wso2, esb, smooks

I am working on Smooks mediator logic in WSo2 ESB. I believe I have everything in place with my smooks configuration file, proxy, and jar files but when I execute my tests i am getting the following error:

```
2015-10-03 23:25:05,903 [-] [vfs-Worker-1] ERROR NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/milyn/Smooks
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.transform.SmooksMediator.createSmooksConfig(SmooksMediator.java:197)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.transform.SmooksMediator.mediate(SmooksMediator.java:92)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:166)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
```

I have downloaded the smooks 1.5 all file and copied the jar files over to my ESB directory:

```
/opt/wso2esb-4.8.1/repository/components/lib
```

I believe this is were I need the jar files to be so I am confused with the error that it cannot find the Smooks class. Is there additional configuration, jars in the wrong lib, etc? I keep trying different things but in the end I am always getting this error. My thought is maybe the ESB is looking in a different place than where I have put the jars? Has anyone had this problem? I would greatly appreciate any help that can be provided. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to copy any jars in order to use smooks mediator in WSO2 ESB. You only need to place your smooks config file in registry and create Proxy service which refers to the above smooks config file to perform transformation. Smooks support comes out of the box with WSO2 ESB. For further information you may refer to blog post [1]

[1] http://ravindraranwala.blogspot.com/2015/03/smooks-mediator-in-wso2-esb.html

Comment: Thanks Ravindra, this is great information. I followed your advice and blog but i am still getting the same error. I went to the ESB console and to the registry and under  /_system/config/smooks I added a resource(smooks-config-ren.xml) choosing upload content from file for the method. Here is my smooks mediator code in the insequence in my proxy: <smooks config-key="conf:/smooks/smooks-config-ren.xml">
            <input type="xml"/> <output type="xml"/> </smooks> I have bounced the server and retested but no luck. Does the smooks-config have to be a certain name?

Comment: Did you remove the jar which you copied before into your lib directory. Please remove that before moving forward. Also you don;t need to have any specific name to your smooks config file. Also I recommend you to use ESB 4.9.0 where we have fixed few bugs related to smooks mediator.